# XAML-referencig static class string[] Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a static class, named `LanguageProvider`. That class contains (obviously, static!) property `LanguageMap`, which is string[] array.

This code is not working, compile-time error:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Languages:LanguageProvider.LanguageMap[0]}" />
```

I got an error

> The member "LanguageMap[0]" is not recognized or is not accessible

If I change to this, app is loading, but another error occurs at the time when code starts to interact with that array: "String[] bla-bla-bla is not valid property for ...Text".

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Languages:LanguageProvider.LanguageMap}" />
```

So, it means, it sees my property. The problem is to get necessary element from the array.

Comment: Solution:Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Lang:LanguageProvider.LanguageMap}, Path=[0]}"

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Source={x:Static cef:Languages.Lang},Path=[0]}"></TextBlock>
```